# How can I hide the title attribute with CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working on Wordpress site which I have modified the main menu to have the logo placed in the center which links to the home page. I've used a `<span>` to achieve this. I have given it a title attribute of home so that when the responsive menu kicks in at 767px it reads Home and not blank. Until it reaches that break point, I want it not displayed so it only shows the logo. I'm having trouble finding the right CSS

you can see the page here http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/

and this is the CSS I'm trying to work with

```
ul#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-3377 a title{ display:none }
```

I feel like I'm close because if I remove a title the menu item disappears.

Comment: you cannot hide a title attribute via css

Comment: Do you know if I can add a title attribute at breakpoint for the responsive dropdown menu?

Comment: you can add/remove the attribute via js, checking the window width on resize event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is create two elements, one with the title and one without, and show or hide the desired element with media queries. Meaning, at 767px, the element without the title attribute will be set to display:none, and the one with the title would be set to display:block (or whatever), and the opposite for over 767px. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily found with the browser inspector. I prefer Chrome. Right-click on the item you want to inspect, and make sure you have the right tag. You will see the css in the inspector for that item. If you hover the section on the top right part of item inspection, a caption will appear with the exact address in the root directory.

Use FTP to make changes or your c-Panel

[image: HOVER THE RED AREA]

Comment: How can this help? You can't style the appearance of a title attribute

Comment: He asked how to find the proper css..This is how...whether what he's trying to do will work or not, that is a different question. no?

Comment: Since OP is trying to hide a title, this doesn't help him.

Comment: You've focused on the (admittedly very bad) title of the question, rather than understanding what the OP is trying to do. While your answer is a literal answer to the question "how to find CSS?", it won't help the OP at all.

Comment: thanks chris, yes the title may be inapropriate. Sorry